# Firebase query delete specific uid Real Time Database (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this data on my firebase:

```
transportation: {
    "car" : {
        "bus" : {
          "toyota" : true,
          "bmw" : true
        },
        "suv" : {
          "honda" : true,
          "toyota" : true,
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to delete all "toyota" data so that my data looks like this:

```
transportation: {
"car" : {
    "bus" : {

      "bmw" : true
    },
    "suv" : {
      "honda" : true,

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way to do is check the value using loop in Javascript manually and delete if it's "toyota".

```
    var firebaseRef= firebase.database().ref('transportation/');
        firebaseRef.on("value", function(data)){
            var datKey=data.key;
            firebase.database().ref('transportation/'+datKey).on("value",function(childData)){
            var childDataKey=childData.key;
            firebase.database().ref('transportation/'+datKey+'/'+childDataKey+'/').on("value",function(data)){
             firebase.database().ref('transportation/'+dataKey+'/'+childDataKey+'toyota').remove(); 
        }
    }
}
```